# Phonegap`s Media does not really work

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a soundboard for Android.
when I play a sound via Media it plays, but if I play it some more times it suddenly does not play anymore.

any ideas?

thanks!

edit:
object and embed seems not to work in WebView.
is there another way to play audio?

another edit: the error code number i get is 5.

edit again: error code 5 is`nt even defined on the phonegap js file:

```
MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED        = 1;
MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NETWORK        = 2;
MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_DECODE         = 3;
MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_NONE_SUPPORTED = 4;
```

Comment: There are obviously multiple problems here. The file not found is one... what about the "suddenly does not play"? Did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a "File not found".
                                                                    .
                                                                    .